# How to resize an image using SDL2

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I have been looking around on many links to find out how to resize an image on SDL2, like in pygame, the "pygame.transform.scale()" function, and I have tried to look to see how to implement one but all of the links are unique to the question or are very unclear to me. How can I implement a function that returns a surface/texture, whatever is used for SDL_RenderCopy() of a newly-resized image, so when I want to use the rectangle it has, it's rectangle is now resized to what i tell it to do. As in:

```
SDL_Surface/SDL_Texture ResizeImage(int width, int height){
    //Process code here to effectively do the equivalent in python of:
    newSurface/Texture = pygame.transform.scale(img, width, height);
    return newSurface/Texture;
}
```

Comment: RenderCopy rescales image if dst rect size differs from src rect. If that's not what you wanted - please describe your problem in more details.

Comment: The problem i am having is that my collisions aren't working properly, the SDL_intersectRect() thinks they are bigger than the arguments in my SDL_Rect rect = {} and likewise with rotating the image, my center point is not really my center point. Rather than rotating it without moving the actual object's x and y coordinates, it is making a radius it spins around with the SDL_RenderCopyEx. Pygame's rotateimage function is what i am trying to recreate here but rotating an object is impossible when i can't find the center if the rect's width/height is not known

Comment: For my arguments in RenderCopy, i use (renderer, texture, NULL, &rect, rotation, &center, SDL_FLIP_NONE)

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. In your question you described function that takes width and height - so clearly you know what your target dimensions are, but then you say "width/height not known"? How could IntersectRect operate on not the rect you've passed but something else, surely you pass wrong rect? And then you suddenly jump to rotations, which is very different thing (e.g. you'll need your own specialised, much slower IntersectRect for that). Rectangle centre is trivial to calculate; SDL even does it itself if you don't provide your own rotation centre.

Comment: I mightn'tve been clear enough, I have a size, but that comes from the orignial image, when i load it. What i want is to rescale the image into a rectangle of dimentions that i give it, so that collisions are pixle perfect. Likewise when i rotate the image, the center is actually the center of the image. As of now, my images have a size that i don't want, and when i try to rendercopy them to a different scale/rect, the image does not fit the sizing at all.

Comment: You don't have to fetch rect from texture. Save your desired rect alongside with image and use it for render/collision detection. Make a struct of `{SDL_Rect rect; SDL_Texture *texture;}` if you can't track it otherwise. Of course it is possible to rescale image to new size, and if you only do it once it may be benefitial to *some* extent; see [SDL_BlitScaled](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_BlitScaled) or target textrure & read pixels.

Comment: That worked for the rescaling, but when i used rendercopyex for rotation, after a few rotatons it begins to start rotating ina bigger and bigger circle. It doesn't make any sense since my width is 64, height is also 64 and my center point is (x+width/2, y+width/2)

Comment: Pass `NULL` instead of centre point; I think it represents point within destination rectangle, so `x` and `y` should not be adjusted here (but I haven't checked it so I may be wrong).

Comment: Wow, honestly thank you so much for your help! That is bloody brilliant. Fixed all my problems, how can i give you a recommendation or rating for something?

Comment: Sorry, one last thing, when i render my newly scaled image, it does some weird thing where the image is there, but it also shows a duplicate, smaller version of the image on the top left part where the image is rendered as well.

Comment: Sorry, no ideas. Probably you render it in more places than you think, try drawing only one image and setting breakpoint on `SDL_RenderCopyEx` to see how many times (and with what parameters) it is being called. If you can't find a problem - consider making [MCCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).